Upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS from 18.4
I am trying to upgrade Ubuntu.
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.

There is one package remaining which needs to be updated:
r-base-dev/bionic-cran40 4.4.2-1.1804.0 all [upgradable from: 4.3.0-1.1804.0]
N: There are 28 additional versions. Please use the '-a' switch to see them.
sudo apt install r-base-dev=4.4.2-1.1804.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base-dev : Depends: libdeflate-dev but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I try to install libdeflate-dev, but not possible:
sudo apt install libdeflate-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libdeflate-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'libdeflate-dev' has no installation candidate

Also trying to use the software updater by pressing 'upgrade'is not helping since it does nothing then.
I would be very thankful for ideas and help!

This question is similar to: How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Also see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Consider fresh installing 24.04 instead

You need to install Ubuntu Pro @ https://ubuntu.com/pro/ .  This will allow you to update 18.04 and then after you install ALL updates you can upgrade to 20.04 and it's free. I will say that I have a dual-boot with 18.04 and 20.04 and 18.04 is better. It uses less CPU and memory and does NOT have Tracker-Miner. Tracker-Miner is baked-into 20.04 and is a resource pig. It uses mass CPU and memory which causes temperature increases and fan RPM to sky-rocket. At any rate, that's the fix. 18.04 is awesome !  Just sayin'.
